# What are parameters to be added in the mcrypt_ decrypt() function in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have this following C# code but i am facing difficulty add the parameters for PHP 
mcrypt_ decrypt().

```
  private string Decrypt(string strText, string sDecrKey)
    {
        string message;
        byte[] rgbKey = new byte[0];
        byte[] rgbIV = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 120, 0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
        byte[] buffer = new byte[strText.Length + 1];
        try
        {
            rgbKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Strings.Left(sDecrKey, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(strText);
            MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(stream2, provider.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.FlushFinalBlock();
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream2.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Exception exception = exception1;
            message = exception.Message;
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
            return message;
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

string mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , 
 string $mode [, string $iv ] )

My Data is-:"iHcKDE0aeDZU3q31ULZcvQ=="

Key-: "&%#@?,:*"

I want to decrypt this data using PHP mcrypt_decrypt () function. I have very less knowledge in C# but good PHP. Please Help me out

```
<?php
$key = pack("nvc*",0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 120, 0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB)
$ciphertext_dec = base64_decode("iHcKDE0aeDZU3q31ULZcvQ==");
$iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
$retval = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv_dec);
echo $retval;
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you post what you have tried in PHP, not the C# code?

Comment: echo  mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES,$key,$ciphertext_dec,MCRYPT_MODE_CFB)

Comment: I am getting the output as ¼p_‡<qÅq0u$,  but this is not the correct one , there must be some appropriate word. Please help me how to get the correct one..

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you need to be creating an `iv`, not running `substr` on `$key` You `substr` the key with `mcrypt_get_key_size(cipher, mode)`, which it seems you are doing with the `iv`.

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
```

And the `iv` should be from a random source, not `$key` cut down. Though, `iv` is optional. This is the only issue I can see.

This is old, but it worked just fine for me when I wrote it. [Cipher.php](https://gist.github.com/bnlucas/5849574)

```
<?php
function encrypt($data, $key = null, $iv = null) {
    $key = (strlen($key) == 0) ? $key = null : $key;

    $key_size = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB); 
    $key = hash("sha256", $key, true); 
    $key = substr($this->key, 0, $key_size);

    if ($iv == null) {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB); 
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    $out = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv); 
    return base64_encode($out);
}

function decrypt($data, $key = null, $iv = null) {
    $key = (strlen($key) == 0) ? $key = null : $key;

    $key_size = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB); 
    $key = hash("sha256", $key, true); 
    $key = substr($this->key, 0, $key_size);

    if ($iv == null) {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB); 
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    $data = base64_decode($data); 
    $out = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
}

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$encrypted = encrypt('my data.', 'my secret key', $iv);
$decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, 'my secret key', $iv);

# $decrypted = 'my data.'
?>
```

**Update**

I have updated [Cipher.php](https://github.com/bnlucas/php-utilities/blob/master/Cipher.php) for easier interaction. You no longer have to specialize an `iv`, `Cipher::encrypt` sets it and attaches it to the encrypted data. `Cipher::decrypt` then extracts it before decrypting the encrypted data.

> The IV is only meant to give an alternative seed to the encryption routines. This IV does not need to be secret at all, though it can be desirable. You even can send it along with your ciphertext without losing security.

Comment: You have your secret `$key`, I ran `sha256` on a string and cut it down with `mcrypt_get_key_size`, then you have your `iv` generated from a random source. For example in `Cipher.php`, you run `$encrypted = $cipher->encrpyt('my data', 'my secret key'); $last_iv = $cipher->getIV(); $decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted, 'my secret key', $last_iv);`

Comment: string strText = 
Conversions.ToString(Interaction.IIf(Information.IsDBNull(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(current["ABC"])), "", RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(current["ABC"])));